# Wallaby not finding tests and @angular/core/testing not finding beforeEach, beforeEachProviders, describe, etc

Tags: angular

I am trying to set up test cases, this is my first time using wallaby.

Inside my project I have a `spec.ts` that I am trying to test, however the follow is showing me the nasty red line under it:

```
import {beforeEach, beforeEachProviders, describe, expect, it, inject, } from '@angular/core/testing';
```

I used angular-cli so everything should be set up and looks correct.

Path this particular is `src-> app-> home -> home.component.spec.ts`

I tried to set up wallaby.js by do the following:

```
 module.exports = function () {

  return {
    files: ['src/app/home/home.component.spec.ts'],

    tests: ['src/app/**/*spec.ts'],

    env: {
      type: 'node',
      runner: 'node',
      params: {
        runner: '--harmony'
      }
    },

    testFramework: 'jest'

  };
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "demo-test-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.24",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.0.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3"
  }
}
```

So I am completely unable to run tests and use this amazing new tool I found. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

The project is on **GitHub**[HERE](https://github.com/drewjocham/TestDemo.git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you got that you needed to import all those things, but that is way outdated. I think this was something way pre-final. Everything (except `inject` and `beforeEachProviders`) is provided globally by jasmine. You should be able to use them all without needing to do anything, as you already have `jasmine-core` and `@types/jasmine` installed.

Also `inject` is still used, but `beforeEachProviders` doesn't even exist anymore in the post-module era. If you are going through a tutorial, I suggest using one that uses at least Angular 2.0.0 final, otherwise a lot of things will be outdated. Or better yet, use [the documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html).

Also, I have never used wallaby, so I am not sure if it is dependent on you having the test framework installed, but if it is, then you should change the test framework to jasmine, as that's what you have installed. Otherwise, I have never used jest, so I couldn't give you any advice on that.